# How to stop git (.gitignore) from tracking minqueue (wordpress plugin) cached changes

Tags: wordpress, git, caching

After entering "git status", I keep getting messages like `wp-content/uploads/minqueue-cache/minqueue-9cbb4cb4-9cb6af13.js`
 even though I have added the following line to .gitignore file:  `/wp-content/uploads/minqueue-cache/*`
. Why is this?

Comment: Maybe delete the / in the beginning of the .gitigone file

Comment: thx. I will try this

Comment: Does `git status` say that the file is modified or untracked?

Comment: And is the `wp-content` folder in the same directory than `.gitignore` or in a subdirectory?

Comment: no, .gitignore is in a folder above, i.e. www.apis.de/wp-content/.. whereby .gitignore is in the folder www.apis.de

Answer (score 1):

The slash in the beginning of `/wp-content/uploads/minqueue-cache/*` means starting from the directory where the `.gitignore` file is in, so your pattern will match all files and folders inside `wp-content/uploads/minqueue-cache/` but not the files inside `www.apis.de/wp-content/uploads/minqueue-cache/`.

If you change the pattern to `wp-content/uploads/minqueue-cache/*` it will match all files and folders in all `wp-content/uploads/minqueue-cache/` folders, no matter where they start.

If you change the pattern to `/www.apis.de/wp-content/uploads/minqueue-cache/*` it will match all files and folders exactly in this one directory.